# Numerical solution of singular ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the singular ODE

$y''+\frac{y'}{r}+p(r)y=0 \ \  with \ \ y(0)=1 \ \ and \ \ y'(0)=0$.

Theoretically such solution exists and is unique if $p$ is nice. Is there a method to numerically solve this equation on some interval $[0, \alpha]$ with an explicit global error bound? I am not sure how to impose the initial condition at the singular point $r=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SLEIGN2](http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/) software package can handle Sturm-Liouville problems with regular as well as singular end points. I believe you can find some papers on that web page that document various aspects of the methods used in the code.